# how to attach file in access database by vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have an application programmed with visual basic.net 2012 , connected to database access 2007 , and there is a table in database contain a field from data type (Attachment) , and I want to attach the files from the program , so which command or function should I have to use to attach the files from vb.net programmaticly.

I used the code below to insert records to the database but I don't know how can I attach a file with this record:

Try

```
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into Objective_Customer_Visits(Customer_Name,SAM_Manager_Id,Visit_Date,Comments) values ('" & comboObjectiveCustVisitCustName2Add.Text & "', " & userId & ", # " & DTPObjectiveCustVisitDate2Add.Value.ToString("yyyy / MM / dd") & " #,'" & textBoxObjectiveCustVisitComent2Add.Text & "' )", con)

        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()

        MsgBox("Add Succeeded")


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Comment: thank you for your responce.

I`ve added the code what I used to insert record in database and what I need is how can attach files with these records.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this, I've just stumbled upon this and am looking into trying to do it myself.